# MKMapView doesn't adhere to animation delay

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm fiddling with my `MKMapView` in Playground, and I'm having trouble animating it's `frame.size.height`. Here's my Playground code:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = vc

let map = MKMapView(frame: vc.view.frame)
map.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
map.autoresizesSubviews = false
vc.view.addSubview(map)

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

    map.frame.size.height = 200

    }, completion: nil)
```

You can tell when the actual animation is occurring by observing the map's red background color. The visible map's height decreases before the `MKMapView`'s height. Setting `autoresizesSubviews = false` doesn't seem to do anything. So why does it seem as if there are two distinct animations?

**UPDATE** In my Playground, I removed all my `MKMapView` subviews, and the `_MKMapContentView`, one of the map's two subviews (the other being the "Legal" `MKAttributionLabel`), was removed, rendering the `MKMapView` with just it's red background. So the `_MKMapContentView` is being resized as a subview, but calling `map.autoresizesSubviews = false` isn't doing the trick. What gives?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack, if you will. I tried animating the map's height using `animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping` and a nonzero delay. My problem was that the `_MKMapContentView` wouldn't adhere to the delay, which is what explained the distinct animations.

So, with a little help from @Matt's [famous delay solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/4848310), I scrapped my function delay and put the entire method in a delay block, so that any (sub)views would animate concurrently.

```
delay(3.5) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

        map.frame.size.height -= 200

        }, completion: nil)

}


func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Bit of a workaround, but it works. Still eager to learn why map's subviews didn't adhere to the function delay, if anyone has an idea.

Answer (score -1):

I think you maybe to user this  to avoid:

```
map.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

vc.view.addSubview(map)

UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 1.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

    map.frame.size.height = 200

    }, completion: 
   map.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked. I'm just using the red background for the example. I asked why it looks as if there are two animations.